# Django: create csv file and load it in view using Javascript

Tags: python, django, csv, web-applications, d3.js

I'm developing a web application which creates visualizations of some data.
The data is taken from third parties, using their APIs, and imported in my database. The importation will be done sporadically, therefore my database will be pretty static.

The visualizations will be dynamically created in JavaScript, using [d3](http://d3js.org/).
When thinking about how to pass (and format) the data from the server to the client I thought I could export it to a .csv file and then load it from javascript (d3 has a builtin csv parser).
This way the csv file doubles as a caching system: it will regenerated (and therefore the database queried), only if it is older than, say,  a week.

My question is: where and how should I save the generated the csv file? `STATIC_ROOT`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, another hardlinked directory?
Also, do you think the csv system is a good idea?

Sorry if the questions may seem useless, I literally picked up both django and d3 less than a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the file in STATIC_ROOT, that would be a suitable location.

Two thoughts on the side:

1. Did you think about locking / mutexing the csv file while it is writing? Or is it not a problem if a client may get half a CSV file if the request comes in at an unlucky moment?
2. CSV is not the standard way to transfer a data series to a JS client. I would probably write a JSON array to the file.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, we usually store the static files - files used by our website to render content (like CSS, JS) under the STATIC_ROOT. Files under the MEDIA_ROOT are usually media files like images and videos that Django lets the webserver to serve. I would store the visualization data file under a `data` directory within my app (which goes under the main django project directory). This [article](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/) is a good resource to structure your django project.

As for using a CSV file for the data file that drives the visualization, I would prefer exporting your data as a JSON, since it is a more compact notation. Also, I would assume decoding JSON in JavaScript would be faster than CSV. Although it would depend on other parameters like the size and structure of data in the file.

Comment: How do I reference the data directory, just hardcode `../data/something.csv` from my html/js file ? Doesn't Django not serve static files?

Comment: I would advice creating a PROJ_ROOT, DATA_ROOT (relative to the PROJECT_ROOT) variables using pythons `os` module. That way you would be safe from difference in path separator notations for Unix and Windows.

Comment: Is a csv not more compact than json as the field names only appear once in the header?  d3 has good tools for handling csv and it's become my preferred format for the job.